# Constructing order embeddings between Boolean algebras from embeddings from their finite subalgebras

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two complete atomic Boolean algebras and $R$ is a relation between $A$ and $B$ with the following property:

> If $Rab$ and $A^\prime$ is a finite Boolean subalgebra of $A$ containing $a$, there is a lattice embedding of $A^\prime$ into $B$ mapping $a$ to $b$ that is a subset of $R$.

I would like to know whether it follows that for any $a$ and $b$ with $Rab$, there is a lattice embedding of $A$ into $B$ mapping $a$ to $b$ that is a subset of $R$. (I suspect that this is false, but I cannot construct a counterexample.)

(By a lattice embedding I mean an injective function that preserves finite meets and joins.)

[In response to bof's answer below, I also want to stipulate that $A$ embeds into $B$.]

Comment: What is an order embedding?

Comment: By an order embedding I just meant a function, $f:X\rightarrow Y$, such that $x\leq y$ if and only if $f(x)\leq f(y)$ for every $x,y\in X$ (so $f$ is therefore injective).

Comment: Ah, sorry! I thought that's all I wanted, but thinking about it I also want it to preserve finite meets and joins. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ the following seems to be a counterexample.

Let $A=\mathcal P(\omega_1)$ and let $B=\mathcal P(\omega_0)$; then $A$ and $B$ are complete Boolean algebras with $|A|=|B|$. I'm not sure what definition of "order embedding" you're using, but I think the fact that $A$ contains a chain of order type $\omega_1$ while $B$ does not implies that there is no order embedding of $A$ into $B$. On the other hand, I think the relation
$$R=\{(a,b)\in A\times B:b\text{ is an infinite and coinfinite subset of }\omega_1\}$$
satisfies your condition.

Instead of $|A|\le|B|$ maybe you want to stipulate that $A$ is order-embeddable in $B$? Or maybe you want to assume GCH?

Comment: Thanks for this! 

I think I was trying to rule out these types of counterexamples with the cardinality restriction, although I see it didn't work. I'm actually most interested in counterexamples where the set of atoms of both $A$ and $B$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, although I'd be interested in an example where A is merely order-embeddable into B.

Comment: I've just noticed: I think this counterexample effectively answers my question with a little tweaking. Let $A=B=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $R=\{(a,b) \in A\times B \mid b \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and $b$ is both infinite and coinfinite in $\mathbb{Q}\}$. $R$ satisfies my condition, but there is no order embedding of $A$ into $B$ that is a subset of $R$ for otherwise it would be an order embedding of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$.